# using 'steps' in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d

I want to make a `3D` shape move through a specified graph; e.g. `y = Sin[x]`, such that it moves up and down.
My working so far has been to use `Manipulate`, and I think I want to use it with 'steps', as in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html), second one down, although I don't know how to use this.
Would this be the way, and if so how do I use it?

Here is what I have so far:

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[{Green, Cuboid[{0, 0, t}], Blue, Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}]}], {t, 0, 3}]
```

I think I want something like:

```
Manipulate[ Graphics3D[{Green, Cuboid[{0, 0, t}], Blue, Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}]}],
            {t, 0, 3, y = Sin[x]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines? Just want to make sure. Hard to put in the comment. If not will delete.

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Green, Cuboid[{t, 0, Sin[t]}]},
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2 Pi , 2 Pi}, {-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}
  ],
 {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi, .1}]
```